# Ruby passing method

Tags: ruby, method-reference, pointfree, first-class-functions

Trying to understand ruby's complexity, but makes no sense so far.

```rb
5.times(method(:puts))
```

Gives error, that doesn't make a lot of sense. Do I have some kind of syntax error or is it not possible to do in ruby?

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
        from (irb):78:in `times'
```

I am trying to do something similar to

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(console.log)
```

and

```java
java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(System.out::println);
```

At the same time these do work:

```rb
method(:puts).call(1)
# and
5.times { |i| puts i }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`times` takes a block argument, which is distinguished from "regular" arguments by an ampersand. You can either pass it an explicit block

```
5.times { |x| puts x }
```

or you can pass it a value with `&`

```
5.times(&method(:puts))
```

Having the block argument treated differently allows us to write methods that look and act a lot like built-in statements. For instance, an infinite loop in Ruby can be written as

```
loop {
  # fun stuff happening in here
}
```

But [`loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) is a method in the core library, not a built-in keyword. We could've written that `loop` function ourselves. `Enumerable` and other modules make heavy use of block arguments to provide friendlier syntax, which is one of the primary goals of Ruby as a language.

Comment: Correct. Each function takes zero or one block arguments, which are indicated with an ampersand. `times` and many looping or enumeration functions work this way. If the documentation says that a function takes a block, you need to either use `{ ... }` (or, equivalently, `do ... end`) or put an ampersand in front of the value.

Comment: `5.times { |x| puts x }` which @SilvioMayolo gives is by far the more idiomatic way.

Comment: @steenslag but makes you mention arguments for no reason. And they could change. Very simple and readable pointfree does not hurt.

Comment: Ruby is designed to be read in pseudo-english. `5.times { |x| puts x }` reads: "5 times, put the number on the screen". `5.times(method(:puts))` reads: "5 times, method the puts". As a Haskeller, I agree that pointfree is very nice in some languages, but Ruby is not one of those languages. The language is designed with blocks in mind.

Comment: FWIW Ruby 2.7-preview1 has [numbered block parameters](https://medium.com/@baweaver/ruby-2-7-numbered-parameters-3f5c06a55fe4) as an experimental feature: `5.times { puts @1 }`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it's supposed to be `5 numbers each puts` instead of `5 numbers each x puts x`. Lightweight pointfree is always more language-like.